How to remove a waypoint on Google maps app after a user has passed that point in a route
This is a mobile app I am working on to use google maps to get routes and add waypoints to the route and their accompanying markers on the map. I intend to make the app to remove a waypoint from the route and maybe its marker to prevent the map from rerouting to show directions of going back to a marker that has already been passed. I have checked out various ways to do this using chatgpt and I am trying to look for online resources but I haven't found good resources.
I tried using various solutions from chatgpt but it is not working. I have also tried coming up with ways to remove waypoints from the route but it did not do what I wanted.
var liveLocation = LocationService.locationData.value
   val liveLocationMarkerState = rememberMarkerState()


   LaunchedEffect(liveLocation) {
       liveLocation?.let { location ->
           liveLocationMarkerState.position = location // Update the position of the marker
       }
   }


   var userLocation by remember { mutableStateOf<LatLng?>(null) }
   val location1 = LatLng(-1.5257693, 36.886121)
   val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
       position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(location1, 12f)
   }


   val markerStatesRoute = remember { mutableStateListOf<LatLng?>(null) }


   // Request location permissions and start location updates if permissions are granted
   val requestPermissionLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
       contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
   ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
       if (isGranted) {
           startLocationService(context)
       } else {
           liveLocation = location1
       }
   }


   // Define a LaunchedEffect to request permissions and start location updates
   LaunchedEffect(requestPermissionLauncher) {
       if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
               context,
               Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
           ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
       ) {
           // Permission is already granted
           startLocationService(context)
       } else {
           // Request permission if not granted
           requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
       }
   }


   var place by remember { mutableStateOf<LatLng?>(null) }


   val markerState = rememberMarkerState(
       position = LatLng(-1.7198691, 34.9230177)
   ) // Example coordinates


   var routePoints by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList<LatLng>()) }


   val apiKey = getApiKeyFromManifest(LocalContext.current)
   var keyy: String = ""
   if (apiKey != null) {
       keyy = apiKey
   } else {
       // Handle error: API key not found
   }


   val waypoint1MarkerState = rememberMarkerState()


   var distanceState: Int? = null
   var durationState: Int? = null


   LaunchedEffect(place) {
       place?.let {
           cameraPositionState.animate(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(it, 15f))
       }
   }

// Not able to implement
   fun hasPassedWaypoint(
       userLocation: LatLng,
       waypoint: LatLng,
       threshold: Double = 0.01
   ): Boolean {
       // Calculate the distance between the user's location and the waypoint
       val distance = sqrt(
           (userLocation.latitude - waypoint.latitude) * (userLocation.latitude - waypoint.latitude) +
                   (userLocation.longitude - waypoint.longitude) * (userLocation.longitude - waypoint.longitude)
       )
       return distance > threshold
   }


   // Filtering out passed waypoints
   // Does not work!!
   val updatedWaypoints = markerStatesRoute
       .filterNotNull()
       .filter { waypoint ->
           liveLocation?.let { location ->
               !hasPassedWaypoint(location, waypoint)
           } ?: true // If liveLocation is null, don't filter out the waypoint
       }


   val waypointsString = markerStatesRoute
       .filterNotNull()
       .joinToString(separator = "|") { marker ->
       "${marker.latitude},${marker.longitude}"
   }


   Log.d("Waypoints", "Waypoints string: $waypointsString")


   LaunchedEffect(place, liveLocation, waypointsString) {
       place?.let {
           try {
               val directionsResponse =
                   RetrofitInstance.directionsService.getDirections(
                       origin = "${liveLocation?.latitude},${liveLocation?.longitude}",
                       destination = "${it.latitude},${it.longitude}",
                       waypoints = waypointsString, // Use pipes to separate waypoints
                       apiKey = "_YOUR_API_KEY_"
                   )


               Log.d("DirectionsService", "DirectionsResponse: $directionsResponse")


               val encodedPolyline =
                   directionsResponse.routes?.firstOrNull()?.overview_polyline?.points
               if (!encodedPolyline.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                   routePoints = decodePolyline(encodedPolyline)
               }


               val route = directionsResponse.routes?.firstOrNull()


               // Update UI or state
               // Example: update distance and duration state
               distanceState = distance
               durationState = duration
           } catch (e: Exception) {
               // Handle exceptions (e.g., API errors)
               e.printStackTrace()
           }
       }
   }


// Initialize the marker state
   val selectedMarkerState = rememberMarkerState()


// Update the camera position and marker position when place changes
   LaunchedEffect(place) {
       place?.let {
           // Move the camera to the new location
           cameraPositionState.animate(
               CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(it, 15f)
           )


           // Update the marker position
           selectedMarkerState.position = it
//            selectedMarkerState.title = ""
       }
   }


   val markerPositionLong = remember { mutableStateOf<LatLng?>(null) }


   // Assuming you have the route driver's ID available
   val routeDriverId = "driver123" // Replace with actual driver ID
   val currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid


   // Start the location service
   LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
       if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
               context,
               Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
           ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
       ) {
           startLocationService(context)
       } else {
           requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
       }
   }


   var locationUpdates by remember { mutableStateOf<LatLng?>(null) }
   val pleaseMarkerState = rememberMarkerState()


   val MarkerStateRemember2 = remember { mutableStateOf<MarkerState?>(null) }


   DisposableEffect(Unit) {
       val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
           override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
               intent?.let {
                   val latitude = it.getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0.0)
                   val longitude = it.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0.0)


                   Log.d("LocationReceiver", "Received Lat: $latitude, Lng: $longitude")


                   // Update the locationUpdates state with the new LatLng
                   locationUpdates = LatLng(latitude, longitude)


               }
           }
       }
       val filter = IntentFilter("LOCATION_UPDATE")
       context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED)


       onDispose {
           context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
       }
   }


// Using a Box to stack the Card on top of the GoogleMap
   Box(
       modifier = Modifier
           .fillMaxSize()
   ) {
       GoogleMap(
           cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
           properties = mapProperties,
           onMapLoaded = {
               // Set up the marker after the map is loaded
               var markerPosition = LatLng(-1.7657693, 38.886121)
               val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
                   .position(markerPosition)
                   .title("Nairobi")
                   .snippet("Marker in Nairobi")
                   .draggable(true)
           },
           onMapLongClick = { latLng ->
               // Add a new MarkerState to the list with the clicked position
               markerStatesRoute.add(latLng)
           }
       ) {
//            User Live location Marker
           Marker(
               state = liveLocationMarkerState,
               title = "Current Location",
               snippet = "This is your current background location",
               icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)
           )


//            Selected Place on Map
           Marker(
               state = selectedMarkerState,
               title = "Destination Location",
               snippet = "Destination location (for now)",
               icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)
           )


           markerStatesRoute.forEach { stop ->
               stop?.let { rememberMarkerState(position = it) }?.let {
                   Marker(
                       state = it,
                       title = "Car Stop",
                       snippet = "This is a car Stop",
                       icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)
                       // Use a custom icon
                   )
               }
           }


